# Bold text in plain text in phpmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Is it possible to bold some text when sending a plain text email via phpmailer? I don't want to use html message. Below is my piece of code.

```
$spec_req = "";
if (strlen($nothing1) > 0) { $spec_req = $spec_req . "
$nothing1 
";}
if ( strlen($spec_req) > 0 ) { $spec_req = "

<b>SPECIAL REQUEST<b> : " . $spec_req;}
```

Mail sending:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->ContentType = 'text/plain';   
$mail->IsHTML(true);  
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $spec_req;
$mail->send();
```

Is it possible with out using Html text? Any help.....

Comment: You want to format text/plain as rich text? Nope - not possible; try it in Notepad. Best you can do is conform to some sort of convention like using asterisks `*THIS IS IMPORTANT*` or something.

Comment: thq, so if need to bold letters in message body, i can use ContentType Html

Comment: Pretty much - only a rich text format (like text/html) would allow you to actually format the text; otherwise it's, well, just text.

Comment: As the others say, it's not possible to style plain text. Quite separate from that, your code is confused. Don't set `ContentType` yourself; PHPMailer will do the right thing if you just call `$mail->isHTML(false);` and set `$mail->Body` to your plain-text content.

Answer (score 1):

No. Plain text is meant to be plain text.

Comment: @mathielo, though it's short, this is actually an accurate answer to the question posted.

Comment: My bad @Synchro. Already removed the comment. Thanks for the correction.